# Creating an R package with devtools and the function "use_rcpp" is instructing me to copy lines of code into a file that does not exist

Tags: r, package, rstudio, devtools

I'm attempting to create a small test R package just to get a hang of the workflow. I've been following the tutorial found here: https://r-pkgs.org/index.html Everything has been running smoothly but eventually I want to add rcpp code to my package and this is where I'm running into problems. The function use_rcpp in the devtools package is supposed to set up your package with everything you need to start adding c++ files. However once the command is done running it tells you to copy and paste comments into a file that does not exist. The tutorial I'm following says the same thing here https://r-pkgs.org/src.html#cpp but just says to add the roxygen tags to your package. It doesn't specify where I need to add them.

The output I'm getting is different from the one in the tutorial but I assume thats just because im running a different version.

The output the function is giving:

> ✔ Setting active project to
>    'R/packages/rcppTester'
>
> ✔ Creating 'src/'
>
> ✔ Adding '*.o', '*.so', '*.dll' to 'src/.gitignore'
>
> ● Copy and paste the following lines into
>   'R/packages/rcppTester/R/rcppTester-package.R':
>
> ## usethis namespace: start
>
> #' @useDynLib rcppTester, .registration = TRUE
>
> ## usethis namespace: end
>
> NULL
>
> [Copied to clipboard]
>
> ✔ Adding 'Rcpp' to LinkingTo field in DESCRIPTION
>
> ✔ Adding 'Rcpp' to Imports field in DESCRIPTION
>
> ● Copy and paste the following lines into
>   'R/packages/rcppTester/R/rcppTester-package.R':
>
> ## usethis namespace: start
>
> #' @importFrom Rcpp sourceCpp
>
> ## usethis namespace: end
>
> NULL
>
> [Copied to clipboard]

Again I have no file named "rcppTester-package.R" and my package is throwing errors when I try and use the cpp files. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have to use `devtools` or `usethis` if they confuse you -- they do add a layer of obfuscation that sometimes obstruct what is happening.

Rcpp itself has a function `Rcpp.package.skeleton()`, and the RStudio IDE has something related (but independent) under 'File -> New Project -> Package with Rcpp'.  I use both. You could start with either and *get a package that compiles*. Both will do that.

Take that as a snapshot and then add roxygen2 documentation.  If you do it manually, you need to run `compileAttributes()` to get the roxygen markup from the C++ file to the R file where `roxygenize()` will see it.  RStudio does both for you automatically.

So to sum up: try separating 'package with Rcpp' and 'package using roxygen' if the joint  'package using Rcpp and roxygen' gives you issues.